# Mocking constructor of a class with jasmine, jest or ts-mockito

Tags: angular, jestjs

I have a group of classes that receive some dependencies outside angular in this way.

```
import {TypeATest} from '...../TypeA.model'
import { TypeBTest } from '..../TypeB.model'
import { SomeDependency } from './services/SomeDependency'
import { SomeAnother } from './services/SomeAnother'
  // ....

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class TestingService {
  this.activeTest: AnyTestType;

  constructor(private readonly injectorService: InjectorService) {}

  loadTest(TypeOfTest) {
    const someDependency = this.injectorService.get(SomeDependency)
    const someAnother = this.injectorService.get(SomeAnother)
      switch(TypeOfTest) {
        case TypeA:
            injector
            this.activeTest = new TypeATest(someDependency, someAnother);
            break;
        case TypeB:
            this.activeTest = new TypeBTest(someAnother);
            break;
      }
  }

  startTest(){
    this.activeTest.start()
  }

// .. more this.activeTest uses...
}
```

I am unit testing the service that loads that external classes but I do not want to create `TypeATest`, `TypeBTest` or similar but just mock the result (they all have the same API) but I am not able to find how to mock them. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Please update your question with more of your code.  Specifically, where does the above switch statement exist in your code and how are `TypeATest` and `TypeBTest` accessed (are they passed in using dependency injection or statically imported?)  Right now we can't see enough of your code to answer.

Comment: Hi @brian-lives-outdoors , I have updated the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The two constructors are *named exports* of their respective modules.

You can mock the entire module using [`jest.mock`](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/jest-object#jestmockmodulename-factory-options) with a module factory:

```ts
jest.mock('...../TypeA.model', () => {
  const start = jest.fn();
  const result = { start };
  return jest.fn(() => result);  
});

test('something', () => {
  // ...
});
```

...or mock only the *named export* of the module using [`jest.spyOn`](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/jest-object#jestspyonobject-methodname):

```ts
import * as TypeB from '..../TypeB.model';

test('something', () => {
  const spy = jest.spyOn(TypeB, 'TypeBTest');
  const start = jest.fn();
  spy.mockReturnValue({ start });
  // ...
})
```

Comment: Thanks for your response! I am not sure though how do you test with the factory that `TypeATest.start` was called.

Comment: I updated my answer to make `start` easier to access and test.  Now the module factory returns *the same object every time* so you can just call it again to get access to the returned object and test its `start` property.  I also pulled the `start` mock out of the *named export* mock to make it easier to access and test.  @distante